# I can't update nvidia 340 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I wanted to update Nvidia (tested, open source) driver on my laptop equipped with a 710M GPU on ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 4.4.0-105-generic), from 340 to a higher version. I tried 384, 375, 352 etc... But with no success.

I am using the canonical graphics-drivers ppa.

The 340 package is removed by the new installs and I removed the residual files manually in order to make sur there will be no trace of 340 on my computer. However, when I restart the pc, I cannot see the freshly installed driver version. What I see instead, is that Nouveau is used and that 340 is listed as another driver to be installed.

Tried this so many times... I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If nvidia-340 is the only proprietary graphics driver that works on your system, then probably nvidia-340 is also the Recommended driver in the results of `ubuntu-drivers devices`, so remove the Canonical graphics-drivers ppa and stop trying to replace nvidia-340 with a different driver that doesn't work on your system.

Comment: Thank you @karel. I suspected the ppa indeed. The reason why I am trying to raise my nvidia driver version is that programs using cuda 8 (or cudnn) crash with an error saying that my nvidia driver is not sufficient and should be raised.

Comment: On the official CUDA website there are CUDA packages for Linux that come bundled with their own Nvidia drivers. This might work on Ubuntu 14.04 or maybe not depending on if your system will boot after installing CUDA. The old version of nvidia-cuda-toolkit 5.5 from the default 14.04 repos runs fine on 14.04. The only guaranteed to work way to get nice updated default repository nvidia-cuda-toolkit is to clean install Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a duplicate, however the discussion you mention brings useful information in relation to my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for correct driver for your graphic card on [nvidia page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) . download it and start manual installation. [read nvidia readme and installation guide](https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/index.html).

before installation or re-installation check compiler  version. linux kernel is normally compiled with gcc so should be nvidia driver.

if this is a re-installation make sure it is clean system.
          sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-340   (remove old driver)

nvidia NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.yyy.run script is using cc for compiling. check version of cc with command cc --version it should be at same version an level as was used to compile the linux kernel.

cc is a link target to gcc. use command sudo update-alternatives --config gcc to select correct version for the gcc. cc can point to clang an that case is necessary to replace the cc link target with command: sudo update-alternatives --config cc

install nvidia kernel driver with command: sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 or manualy run NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-xxx.yyy.run script as root user.

check is display is using nvidia driver with command: sudo lshw -C display.

check if nvidia driver is in use :lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA'

after instalation generate proper xorg.conf file with command sudo nvidia-xconfig. normally nvidia-xconfig set proper value of DPI for your monitor.

to adopt proper DPI setting for your monitor specify your desired DPI by placing desired value inside section "Monitor" of your /etc/X11/xorg.conf. for example: Option "DPI" "96 x 96"

logout an login to apply new settings for the X server.